# Increasing array length dynamically while adding objects to array

Tags: java, arrays, object, dynamic, copy

I wrote a method that adds an object to an array of objects. If the array gets full, it should make a new array and double the old array size using Arrays.copyOf. However, it results in successfully increasing the array size, but it fills the new slots with duplicates of the last object from the old array.

Here is the add method from the ClassRoster class:

```
void add(Student newStudent){
    int i=0;
    while(i != classSize){
        if(roster[i] == null{
            roster[i] = newStudent;
            break;
        }
        if(i>=roster.legnth){
            Student[] newRoster = Arrays.copyOf(roster, 2*roster.length);
            roster = newRoster;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

The ClassRoster class also has a constructor that is initialized with an array size of 10.

```
public class ClassRoster{
    private Student[] roster;
    final int SIZE = 10;


    public ClassRoster(){
       this.roster = new Student[SIZE];
    }
```

The main method uses this method to add Student objects from an input text file:

```
ClassRoster firstRoster = new ClassRoster();
scan = new Scanner(inputFile).useDelimiter(",|\\n");
while(scan.hasNext()){
    String name = scan.next();
    int gradeLevel = scan.nextInt();
    int testGrade = scan.nextInt();
    Student newStudent = new Student(name,gradeLevel,testGrade);
    firstRoster.add(newStudent);
    System.out.printf(firstRoster.toString());
}
```

The text file would look like this:

```
John,12,95
Mary,11,99
Bob,9,87
Larry,10,90
Steph,11,89
James,12,95
Susan,11,88
Harry,9,78
Ann,10,92
Holly,9,86
Sammy,12,75
Jen,11,90
Katrina,9,94
```

However, the program produces an output like this:

```
John,12,95
Mary,11,99
Bob,9,87
Larry,10,90
Steph,11,89
James,12,95
Susan,11,88
Harry,9,78
Ann,10,92
Holly,9,86
Holly,9,86
Holly,9,86
Holly,9,86
```

It seems to that it just copies the last object of the old array after it reaches its maximum size of 10. After Holly, it doesn't print out the rest of the students.

SOLUTION

Figured out the problem. The array was never doubled or increased in size. The array still has a size of 10 because it never reenters the while loop in the add method since `while(i != classSize)` is now false. Therefore, the code never reaches the `if (i>=roster.length)` portion of the method and does not increase the size of the array. The program kept printing duplicates of Holly because `scan.hasNext()` was true. It kept returning the last object in the array to the
`System.out.printf(firstRoster.toString());`. It was just printing to the console but not actually being assigned to an index in the array.

For the solution, I just modified the while statement in the add method:

`while(i != classSize || i >= roster.length)`

Comment: Why do you protect the array assignment if it's null? It seems like you will throw away people if you do that. I don't use Arrays.copyOf, so I don't know what that leaves in the newly created slots. It might be interesting to dump the array before and after that portion of the code.

Comment: You haven't shown us your actual code since the code above doesn't even compile. @JosephLarson [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T%5B%5D,int)) will set new slots to `null`. (If the code above were corrected so it did compile, it would apparently set ALL `null` entries to the `newStudent`.)

Comment: @DavidConrad that's what I assumed, but other than a really weird data dump method, I couldn't figure out why he'd see the output he's displayed. It's probably his print code.

Comment: @DavidConrad@JosephLarson My bad, forgot to add the main code in the post. I edited it and added it.

Comment: Why don't you use `ArrayList` instead of trying to re-implement its behavior yourself?

Answer (score 1):

If `classSize` is the same as `roster.length` then you should change its value when you double the size of the array (although you should not keep a separate variable since you have `roster.length` unless you need it for something else). 
When you double the size of the array then you can add the new item at the `classSize` position (`classSize` is still equal to the previous size) and break the loop:

```
void add(Student newStudent){
    int i=0;
    while(i != classSize){
        if(roster[i] == null{
            roster[i] = newStudent;
            break;
        }
        if(i >= roster.legnth){
            Student[] newRoster = Arrays.copyOf(roster, 2 * roster.length);
            roster = newRoster;
            roster[classSize] = newStudent;
            classSize = roster.length;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's still giving me the same result. I've tried using classSize only and roster.length only but it's still the same.

Comment: The above loop as it is can't save  the same `newStudent` object more than once in the array, because as soon as it stores it to some position it then exits the loop. So debug to find at which point (if there exists) you save the same `newStudent` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

Figured out the problem. The array was never doubled or increased in size. The array still has a size of 10 because it never reenters the while loop in the add method since `while(i != classSize)` is now false. Therefore, the code never reaches the `if (i>=roster.length)` portion of the method and does not increase the size of the array. The program kept printing duplicates of Holly because `scan.hasNext()` was true. It kept returning the last object in the array to the `System.out.printf(firstRoster.toString());`. It was just printing to the console but not actually being assigned to an index in the array.

For the solution, I just modified the while statement in the add method:

`while(i != classSize || i >= roster.length)`